# How to deal with errors in some financial formulas in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have a phpexcel generated file that generates an error on opening. The file generates the error only if I include a formula in a specific cell. To debug I wrote the formula in the excel without the leading '=' to be treated as text and once opening the excel without issues I put there the missining operand. The result is that the formula is working fine but:

- in some occasions it provides '#NUM' error that is ok: means the formula has found no results. Since it is the Internal Rate of Return (IRR) formula that's ok. Excel is trying to guess a number that puts to zero an equation and it is not for sure that you get a result.
- in one occasion it gives you '#DIV/0' and this is also ok. IN some occasions the formula can give values that are so close to zero that they are actually evaluated to zero.

I have found no other reasons why the excel should report the formula as corrupted. Note that if I ask excel to try to fix the file it reports to have only removed the formula from that cell. I have no more infoes for debug. 
This is the code I use to write the formula:

```
$row_array5[15] = "=TIR.COST(U$k:EJ$k;$tasso1%)";
```

the whole `$row_array5` is then written to excel with:

```
$ews->fromArray($row_array5, ' ', 'A'.$k);
```

where $k is the row number.

NOTE: TIR.COST is the italian for IRR.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHPExcel, but with regard to Excel:  What is the data?  IRR will also generate `#NUM!` error if there does not exist at least one positive and one negative value in the range being tested.  Could this be causing the problem you see?

Comment: Actually I am not worried about the results of the formula. The point is that if I include it the file is marked as containing some invalid data (that formula) when coming from the phpexcel script. If I add the formula manually excel doesn't complain at all. All the other formula on the same file work fine.

Comment: I guess I was not clear.  Will PHPExcel error if the data to which the formula refers is not valid data?  VBA in Excel will sometimes do that, when trying to write a formula to a cell.

Comment: What locale setting do you have for the PHPExcel calculation engine?

Comment: didn't set one. Anyway it doesn't work both specifying the formula with the english or the italian name. In both cases without the leading = and then adding it manually in excel is the only way to make it work

Comment: English name for the function, ___and___ use `,` rather than `;` as an argument separator

Comment: Same result. The comma instead of the semicolon doesn't affect the final result.

Comment: Well a semi-colon should throw a serious error because it renders the whole formula invlaid; and use of Italian function names will result in unrecognised function names in Excel

Comment: am I not supposed to write the formula right as I should put it directly in the cell? Ok for the english name but excel uses semicolon `;` between items in the formula. Or I am missing something?

Comment: No, Excel doesn't (always) use a `;`..... Excel uses a comma (`,`) internally (US setting), but converts it to other characters like `;` within the GUI, based on locale settings.... PHPExcel defaults to this US setting (as described in the docs), but allows you to override it with a locale setting that lets you use the translator for function names, and a locale-specific separator

Comment: good to know a bit more about excel but the issue is always there even with , as a separator and english version of the formula :(

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the hint. In the end I realized that I missed to replace the decimal separator in the formula... Fixed and working as a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out